# cisco 5548 - version 5.2 equivalent command to "service unsupported-transceiver"

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, cisco-nexus

In my new cisco switch version,

kickstart: version 5.2(1)N1(7)
system:    version 5.2(1)N1(7)

In this latest IOS , it doesnt have service command.

Could any one help , the equivalent command for "**service unsupported-transceiver**"

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the new switches do not support these commands for shady SFP/SFP+'s. It has always been a **unofficial command** anyway. If the command is not there, the only thing you can do is to tweak the GBIC, but that's a whole different story.

Answer (score 0):

That version isn't a regular IOS version, but IOS-XR. `service unsupported-transceiver` isn't available in that release it seems. I've never used it so use it at your own risk, but it looks like this is the command:

```
transceiver permit pid all
```

Comment: Hi teun, This command also not exists.

Comment: Did you test it in config mode?

Comment: Yes..   Rack(config)# transceiver  
                     ^
% Invalid command at '^' marker.
Rack(config)#

Comment: No idea then, sorry.